# Set a height margin on window scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get an alert when scrolling on a page has reached 500px above the end of that page. (Skipping the footer to autoload new content.)

Tried a lot with offsetHeight but can't get it to work.

This is the function I use, but need to adjust it to -500 - if I understand correctly.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
    alert('more please...');
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a small formula to see whether you have scrolled into the save area:

```
(SaveHeight + ScrollTop) > (ContentHeight - WindowHeight)
```

Set the height of the save area:

```
const SaveHeight =  500;
```

Get the values with these selectors:

```
let ScrollTop =     $(document).scrollTop();
let ContentHeight = $("#content").height(); // or $(document).height()
let WindowHeight =  $(window).height();
```

Putting it all together:

```js
// Config
   const SaveHeight =  500;
   
// Set indicator
   $("#indicator").height(SaveHeight);
   
// Scroll event
   $(document).on("scroll", function() {
      
   // Get values
      ScrollTop =     Math.round($(document).scrollTop());
      ContentHeight = Math.round($("#content").height());
      WindowHeight =  Math.round($(window).height());
      
   // Show live values
      scrollis = SaveHeight + ScrollTop;
      scrollwas = ContentHeight - WindowHeight;
      calculation = " ("+SaveHeight+" + "+ScrollTop+") > ("+ContentHeight+" - "+WindowHeight+")<br>"+scrollis+" > "+scrollwas+"";
      $("#calculation").html(calculation);
      
   // React on values
      if (SaveHeight + ScrollTop > ContentHeight - WindowHeight) {
         $("#content").css("background", "#ffeeee");
      }
      else {
         $("#content").css("background", "#ffffff");
      }
      
   });
```

```css
#content { height: 2000px; position: relative; }
#indicator { height: 100vh; background: red; width: 10px; position: absolute; bottom: 0px; }
#calculation { position: fixed; top: 10px; right: 10px; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <!-- Your content -->
  <div id="indicator"></div>
<div>
<div id="calculation">Scroll down</div>
```

Some notes:

- Most of the snippets code is just to visualize what is going on...
- Jquerys [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is recommended

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks @sefzig! I will have to work on this all first.

Comment: Superthanks for the efforts here, Works great, and appreciate the clear comments!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, @KJS :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you this is what you are looking for

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(document).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - 500) {
        alert('more please...');
    }
}
```